# Internet Explorer 9 and jQuery 2.2.1

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

I downloaded an IE9 virtual machine from https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/windows/

I downloaded jQuery 2.2.1
The jQuery website says Internet Explorer 9 is supported.

I made this html file.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <script src="jquery-2.2.1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hello
    </body>
</html>
```

I open this html file in IE9 and I get this error:

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener;
jquery-2.2.1.js, line 3578 character 1
```

What's going on? Is this a bug in jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's going on? Is this a bug in jQuery?

You must set a `doctype` or you'll fall back into Explorer's compatibility mode ("quirks mode"), which will break jQuery 2 since it's essentially running in a browser only as good as Explorer 5.5 (applicable to IE 9 and earlier).

> *Standards mode provides the greatest support for the latest standards, such as HTML5, CSS3, SVG, and others. This is the preferred mode for new public websites.*<sup>1</sup>
>
> ...
>
> *If Internet Explorer encounters a webpage that doesn't contain a `<!DOCTYPE>` element, it opens the page in quirks mode, which can lead to several unexpected side-effects*<sup>1</sup>
>
> ...
>
> *Windows Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, quirks mode restricted the webpage to the features supported by Microsoft Internet Explorer 5.5.*<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1</sup>See:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx

Ensure the page opens in standards mode...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge;" />
        <title>Title</title>
        <script src="jquery-2.2.1.js"></script>
        ....
```